# Pull changing image from img src with php

Tags: php, image

I'm trying to use PHP to pull an image from weather.com (the current condition image), but I can't figure out how to do so, as the image changes when the weather does, so I cant link directly to it. Is there a way to pull an image from an  tag so when the image source change, PHP gets the new one?

Here's the  tag I would like PHP to pull from:

```
<img class="wx-weather-icon" src="http://s.imwx.com/v.20120328.084208//img/wxicon/120/32.png" height="93" width="93" alt="Sunny">
```

Comment: This doesn't belong here; it belongs on StackOverflow. Regardless, you're going to want to use a regular expression to grab the tag, or use a document crawler to pull the tag out. Try playing around with these, and if you still can't figure it out, post what you have to StackOverflow and they'll help you there.

Answer (score 1):

[SimpleHTMLDOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

would possibly be your best bet, then you can go ahead and do the following

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.weather.com/');

foreach($html->find('img[class=wx-weather-icon]') as $element) {
   echo $element->src;
}
```